react-infinite-scroll-component and @tanstack/react-query problem
I am using @tanstack/react-query and react-infinite-scroll-component libraries together to create my chat application. To get paginated chat messages i got problem with react-infinite-scroll-component. I could not get 2nd page when I scrolled it up. Because I am using inverse attribute of <InfiniteScroll /> component.
Here you can see the sample project link StackBlits Project.
